# Why is opening a file Word 2013 Preview stating “Error! Use the home tab to apply Title to the text that you want to appear here.”

Tags: microsoft-word, word-2013-preview

When opening a Word 2010 file in Word 2013 Preview I get the following error in the Header part of the document:

> Error! Use the home tab to apply Title to the text that you want to appear here

What does this mean? And how do I fix this?

Comment: The OOXML looks like a regular dynamic field, except for the text in the run. Is there an XML tag on level of the OOXML based on which can get detected that this error occurred? Or can this only get detected based on the message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document was created in a Dutch version of Word 2010 and now edited in an English version of Word 2013. The field code read:

```
{ STYLEREF Titel \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

'Titel' is the Dutch word for Title. So changing this to:

```
{ STYLEREF Title \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I add the Ialian version of this weird error, because looking for it on google I only find... documents containing the error!

> Errore. Per applicare 0 al testo da visualizzare in questo punto, utilizzare la scheda Home.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to view the field contents, which will look like:

> Figure  {STYLEREF 0 \s}-{SEQ Figure * ARABIC \s 0}

In my case (caption of a figure) "0" refers to the style of first level of numbered list, i.e. the style of the section where the figure is contained.
By replacing both "0" by "1" I correctly get:

> Figure 3-1

Indeed the figure is in sub-section 3.4.2 and I selected "title 1" as level for the figure number.
If I select "title 2" I get

> Figure 3.4-1

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error that was [reported by @jumpack](https://superuser.com/a/764501/167207). However, in my case the error is related to Portuguese version, so the word **"Título"** must be change to **"Title"**

> Error! Use the Home tab to apply Título to the text that you want to appear here

To do this enable/disable StyleRef format using ALT + F9 keyborad shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very poorly worded error message. It means that the name of the style in a STYLEREF field (often used in headers and footers to pick up text from a heading) is misspelled or has an extra space, as can happen if you edit a STYLEREF field manually. It would be better if the message simply said, "No such style" or similar. The reference to the Home tab is because that's where you can access the list of styles in the document.

Note: This error message also occurs in MS Word 2007 and possibly earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this for 2 days before I found the answer (see bald spot). The problem lies in that the Figure, Title, Titel, etc dialog box has a Numbering option. Select that, and a second dialog box opens. Clear the check mark to include chapter number.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the field code (or system language setting), one could also change the name of the target quick style in Home tab (to `Title` in this particular case), save, then reopen the file. The advantage of doing so is that you don't have to do further modification on a third computer.

For example, the `Title` style will be (automatically) renamed as `Titel` under Dutch-language environment and `目录` under Chinese. By manually renaming the style one can prevent this language-related change.

Comment: Fair enough. All wrongs reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the numbering system is consistent, Word may have return your numbering system for Tables and Figures back to the default.  When you try to add a new caption with a different numbering system you get this error message.  But after re-align the numbering system the error message should go away

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and these steps solved it automatically:

- Go to the "References" tab
- Then "Insert Caption"
- Select the caption label you want under "Options"
- Click on "Numbering"
- Choose the format you want
- Ok
- Ok